# Baking a Pie in a Stainless Steel

Tags: equipment, pie, stainless-steel

My ceramic pie dish broke recently and I only have stainless steel as well as cast irons in the approximate size of my desired pie.

Can I bake my pie in these or will something go terribly wrong? And what precautions ought I take (baking at a lower temp, etc.) using pans to cook a pie

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. I have often baked pies and tarts in metal dishes: one can even buy metal dishes with removable bottoms specifically for baking tarts.

In order of heat capacity, stainless steel has the least heat capacity, then cast iron, then ceramic. The metal pans are more conductive (and darker) so you will find your crust cooks slightly more quickly. I would bear this in mind particularly if you are blind-baking a pie or tart crust.

I suggest you *do not* vary the temperature, since this just introduces an extra variable, and will affect how the filling cooks as well as the crust.